# How do I correct and countersign a check with date error?

Tags: checking-account

[image: Picture of a check with the date filled in as January 7th 2015]

I am not sure how I countersign after correcting the date I previously wrote in error.

I wrote the date as 7-1-2015 (DAY/MONTH/YEAR) which led to the bank telling me that they can't receive the depositing checks. So I have to correct and now countersign it. Where, which part on check should I countersign? Honestly, I am not also sure how to countersign it. Does it have procedure or do I have to write a countersigning letter?

Comment: Did you write the check to yourself or someone else? What date is supposed to be on it? Can you call the bank and ask them the best course of action? What country are you in (regulations may differ)? In the US, most banks would have you either correct the date and initial next to it or void/stop payment on the original check and write a new one.

Comment: Hi, I am writing on behalf of the owner which is my mother.
Sorry for not mentioning that I am not from US/EU but in Asia. I can't find a good place to post my problem until I've found this place.

The bank just asked me to correct the date format and countersign it all 12 checks which date was written in 7-1-2015 to 7-12-2015 (DAY/MONTH/YEAR). So, I have corrected the date format and just have to countersign it.
What do you mean by "initial"? I have to write my signature, right?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you could change the "7" to a "2" pretty easily and it might not even look like an edit and then the date will be Feb 1, which is in the past and will be accepted. Then put your initials above the date after changing it.

Similar question:

[How to correct a mistake made when writing a check?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/how-to-correct-a-mistake-made-when-writing-a-check)

Comment: Never understood why the US does dates in m/d/y format when the rest of the world is d/m/y, which seems more logical.

Comment: In the US it would be Feb 1 (m/d/y)

Comment: OP Photoshopped that day/month/year in red onto the image. It's not really on the check itself.