# Multi city cheque India

Tags: india, banking, check

In India, Can I write a multi-city cheque to myself (Self cheque) and present to non-home branch to withdraw money? If yes, Can bank deny this transaction? eg: [SBI policy](https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/documents/42725/57478/POLICY_ON_MULTI_CITY_CHEQUE/b88db6b1-652b-408b-88f6-2d8c95e26d2b) on MCC says:

> Cash Payment at Non-Home Branch-Maximum limit
>
> As prevailing time to time. Presently, it is as under:
>
> i) ‘P’ segment: Rs.50000/- for self. No cash payment to third parties

Also from their [website](https://www.sbi.co.in/portal/web/personal-banking/multi-city-cheques):

> The MCC facility is to be used only for genuine transactions / bonafide remittances. No cash payments will be made to third parties at other branches.

What is "genuine transactions / bonafide remittances"?

Moreover, what does "No cash payment to third parties" means? Suppose someone gave me a cheque and I don't have an account in that bank (or I am out of town, so I go to a non-home branch), how can I get the money in **cash**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In India, Can I write a multi-city cheque to myself (Self cheque) and present to non-home branch to withdraw money? If yes, Can bank deny this transaction?

Yes you can. There are limitations on the amount advised from time to time.

> What is "genuine transactions / bonafide remittances"?

The multi-city cheque were created / issued to ease the clearing time. Previously outstation cheques would take max of 1 month by law. having a Multi-City cheque reduces this to max of 3 days. So what the clause says is one should use MCC to make genuine payments for parties outside your city. These should not be used as conduits for money laundering activities.

> No cash payment to third parties

It means cash payment is not given to others except to account holder in non-home branch. A 3rd party can withdraw from home branch.

> Suppose someone gave me a cheque and I don't have an account in that bank (or I am out of town, so I go to a non-home branch), how can I get the money in cash?

You can't. Generally I have seen that this can be en-cashed in the same city and not necessarily the same branch. However its been sometime when I have done this. Best is deposit this into your Bank or have payer initiate an IMPS/NEFT transfer.