# I am missing one cent

Tags: check

What if I wrote 2 cheques for 151.53, therefore a total of 303.06$ will be due. and I have 303.05$ in the bank? Will one cheque bounce?

Can I just change the decimal of one cheque to be 151.52 and put my intials and the other to be 151.53? Or will that be deemed suspicious and it will be voided?

- I'm asking this because, If I do rewrite this cheque I need to have a signature from my mentor, which he is out of town and this cheque is due soon.

Comment: And a visit to the bank to deposit one penny is out of the question?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer We don't have pennys anymore in Canada, so I guess the best way is to deposit a nickel? But if that wasn't a solution would changing a penny on a cheque deem it void?

Comment: So the real question is, can you alter the amount on a check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct a mistake made when writing a check?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/how-to-correct-a-mistake-made-when-writing-a-check)  I would imagine over a penny they wouldn't raise a fuss over an alteration, but I wouldn't risk it on an important payment.

Comment: @HartCO, Yes. I guess that creates unusable cheques I presume?

Comment: @HartCO well it's a cheque for a charity donation.

Comment: If you can't change the cheques, go to the bank and deposit one cent.

Answer (score -4):

> What if I wrote 2 cheques for 151.53, therefore a total of 303.06$ will be due. and I have 303.05$ in the bank? Will one cheque bounce?

Yes, obviously...

Comment: A bank may be inclined to let you go one cent overdrawn. Of course they will then charge you a fee for going overdrawn.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Many US account agreements have a rule that the fee does not apply to transactions that overdraw by less than $1.  (It seems unwise to abuse this rule)